# Xcode Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, cpu-architecture, undefined-symbol

I have taken over a Xcode project from another developer and trying to get the code up and running on my local computer.

I am getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

This is my log file from Xcode:

```
 Ld
/Users/etiennelouw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheBridesOffice-dikntijbbbpirgcsdaggnwtzafqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TheBridesOffice.app/TheBridesOffice
normal x86_64

    cd "/Users/etiennelouw/Downloads/App (1)/TheBridesOffice"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk
-L/Users/etiennelouw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheBridesOffice-dikntijbbbpirgcsdaggnwtzafqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-F/Users/etiennelouw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheBridesOffice-dikntijbbbpirgcsdaggnwtzafqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-F/Users/etiennelouw/Downloads/App\ (1)/TheBridesOffice/TheBridesOffice/Class/Addition/Parse
-F/Users/etiennelouw/Downloads/App\ (1)/TheBridesOffice/TheBridesOffice/Class/Addition/Facebook
-F/Users/etiennelouw/Documents/FacebookSDK -filelist /Users/etiennelouw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheBridesOffice-dikntijbbbpirgcsdaggnwtzafqj/Build/Intermediates/TheBridesOffice.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TheBridesOffice.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TheBridesOffice.LinkFileList
-Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lsqlite3 -framework Bolts -framework MobileCoreServices -framework FBSDKShareKit -framework ParseCrashReporting -framework
FBSDKMessengerShareKit -framework FBAudienceNetwork -framework
FBSDKCoreKit -framework ParseFacebookUtilsV4 -framework FBSDKLoginKit
-framework Parse -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreImage -framework ParseFacebookUtils
-framework QuartzCore -framework ParseUI -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/etiennelouw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheBridesOffice-dikntijbbbpirgcsdaggnwtzafqj/Build/Intermediates/TheBridesOffice.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TheBridesOffice.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TheBridesOffice_dependency_info.dat
-o /Users/etiennelouw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheBridesOffice-dikntijbbbpirgcsdaggnwtzafqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TheBridesOffice.app/TheBridesOffice



 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

   "_FBSDKAppEventNameFBSessionNativeAppSwitchLoginDialogResult",
referenced from:

      -[FBSDKLoginManagerLogger logNativeAppDialogResult:dialogDuration:] in
FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginManagerLogger.o)

   "_FBSDKDialogConfigurationNameLogin", referenced from:

      -[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithBehavior:serverConfiguration:serverConfigurationLoadError:]
in FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginManager.o)

      -[FBSDKLoginManager(Native) performBrowserLogInWithParameters:handler:] in
FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginManager.o)

   "_FBSDKMonotonicTimeGetCurrentSeconds", referenced from:

      -[FBSDKLoginManagerLogger parametersWithTimeStampAndClientState:forAuthMethod:] in
FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginManagerLogger.o)

 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
invocation)
```

Here is what I have under Architecture:
[Architectur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUTr0.png)

Here is my Framework files that I have imported following the facebook SDK getting started guide:
[Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSrYa.png)

Comment: What do you have under Build Settings -> Architecture? Are you requiring X64 instead of $ARCH_STANDARD (armv7, arm64).  Check the FB pod target too.

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshots for the architecture, I have been trying to add other fields as I have seen online that this might be the issue, but no matter what fields I have entered I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Quote to code markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your project missing dependency while linking because `FBSDKLoginKit.framework` is missing on linking stage.

Try to recheck you configuration via Facebook Guide - [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/#sdk-project).

Comment: I have gone through this getting started guide as well as a parse and facebook sdk getting started tutorial and it is still giving the error, I have removed duplicates from Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries and still the same error. Not sure where else to look, any ideas would be amazing to try.

Comment: So it was close to this, there seemed to be a duplicate folder in the Framework Search Paths that was getting the incorrect version of the FB SDK, so removed that and it has now successfully built.

Comment: Nice to hear. Sorry for the delay with the answer, but I'm glad that my thoughts help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`